# Required clarification about GPL licence for creating extensions of GPL software

Tags: licensing, gpl, wordpress

I asked a [question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/278592/i-am-using-the-fat-free-framework-does-my-web-app-need-to-be-under-the-gpl-lice) and received quite good answers. I read all answers and other sources about my question.

I concluded that if I write my code and distribute it to my clients for a free under my own license and ask them to download F3 separately at their own, my code won't be covered under GPL license anymore as I am not providing the GPL code with my distribution.

For example, people are selling WordPress themes and plugins which are not covered by GPL but WordPress is licensed under GPL. Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends. You should ask a lawyer. Actually, you should ask `n` lawyers, one for each country you intend to distribute your software to.

Comment: But how this model works for Themes made for Opencart and Wordpress and  other GPL based CMS

Comment: Themes are not Derived Works. Whether or not your software is a Derived Work depends, and can ultimately only be answered by a judge. Please, if you are making a legal decision that could cost you your life savings or even land you in jail, *ask a frigging lawyer* and not some random dude on the Internet. This is a *Programming* website, not a *Legal* website. We know about Programming. We don't know about the Law.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: while this isn't a legal website, software licensing is on topic, and we are capable of thinking for ourselves.